# What class/method in Spring Security handles redirecting to /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}? Need to override for container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We're deploying our API in a docker container behind a gateway. Everything behind the gateway is http, not https. As a result, when Spring Security tries to redirect a user to the authorization Uri, it does it to http which throws a 404. *(because when the redirect hits the user's browser, the browser cannot find it at http, only at https)*

I have been unable to find where this redirect occurs. For example, if a user goes to `https://thecompany.com/securedpage`, and Spring Security sees they're not authenticated (no JWT), some code will then redirect to `/oauth2/authorization/{regsitrationId}`.

I found where the resolving is done (`OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain)` but I cannot seem to find where the redirect occurs. I walked all the way down the Security Filer Chain, but even at the last one, there was no header in the response for a redirect, nor was there a status of `302`.

How can I override the redirect to enforce https?

Comment: What gateway do you use? The gateway should fix this problem not the application server.

Comment: Are you using WebFlux?

Comment: @NatFar yes, i am using webflux

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the chapter "[Proxy Server Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-proxy-server)" from spring security documentation to configure your gateway ?

You need to make your application aware of that configuration (https --> gateway --> http --> your_app) by setting X-Forwarded headers and by configuring the ForwardedHeaderFilter in your app